# Addition of infinite cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Recently while trying to prove the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, I stumbled upon a fact that, if $m$ and $n$ are two cardinal numbers such that atleast one of them is infinite, then $m+n= \max\{m,n\}$.
Now I can prove this fact when say, $m$ is any infinite cardinal and $n \leq \aleph_0$. But I can't go beyond that. So I searched a bit for a more general proof but couldn't find any. So any information related to this will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How much background do you have with ordinal numbers?

Comment: Perhaps you should include the known properties of cardinal addition, if not the definition.  E.g. is it clear the sum is commutative?

Comment: I know that cardinal numbers have their own arithmetic which is a kind of generalization of the arithmetic of natural numbers. I sort of know the corresponding properties of these arithmetic operations, like addition is commutative n all. And thats all. But if you guys provide some references I am very much willing to read the prerequisites. Thanks by d way.

Comment: @AkashBanerjee Robert is an important question: how much do you know about ordinals? Because the easiest way to prove it is using ordinals

Comment: Nothing deep about ordinals. But I am willing to read all the prerequisites.

Comment: Can you provide some references?